# Create custom Audio/Video chat server using WebRTC for iOS?

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, webrtc

I have been studying WebRTC from last 2 days but couldn't understand how to develop and stand up a server based on WebRTC for iOS.

I really don't want to use any 3rd party Audio/Video chat service providers in my application even if they are WebRTC based. I want to create my own WebRTC based custom Audio/Video chat.

I just need a startup guide for developing WebRTC based chat server.

Comment: is there anyone who can answer my question?

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things:

1. You will have to work with the NativeAPI and compile for iOS, this [tutorial should help](http://ninjanetic.com/how-to-get-started-with-webrtc-and-ios-without-wasting-10-hours-of-your-life/), this is for the iOS client side only.
2. If you chat is only one-to-one a simple [websocket](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/websocket/) or [socket.io with node.js](http://bloggeek.me/nodejs-webrtc/) for your signalling server should be simple enough
3. If you want numerous parties in the same chat, you will either have to handle all the individual connections(numerous individual peer connections for each device connecting) or implement a type of MCU, [licode is an EXAMPLE of such](https://github.com/ging/licode/tree/master/erizo)

Those links are just examples of how people have done similar things before, you should not have to utilize their libraries or their solutions. But, you WILL have to use the WebRTC Native API, handle numerous peerconnections for each client(or create your own MCU server), and handle the signalling between each client(for connection start up and tear down).

Answer (score 1):

You can also try **Icelink** api provided by [Frozen mountain](https://www.frozenmountain.com/downloads#icelink)
They have provided free trials for iOS, android , web client, windows phone.
Also they have provided their own turn and stun servers which can be only used in windows server 2013. Overall library is very well documented and easy to use.
You need to register yourself to download the api, which is free of cost.
Hope it meet your requirements.
Good luck